# htaccess redirects but issue with https

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect

https://www.example.com/test

to

https://user.example.com/test

I did it using

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/?$ https://user.example.com/test [NC,R=301,L]
```

Now my issue is, if I load user.example.com/test or http://user.example.com/test

I get user.example.com/test but I need to get https://user.example.com/test

How do I modify or add a rule to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for https in your rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/?$ https://user.example.com/test [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked. Thanks.

I have more rule to add

it doesn't redirect to https://user.example.com/test from example.com/test and http://example.com/test

I really appreciate if you could add that rule also to the existing

Comment: @Peter it already covers those scenarios to and I tested it too. Clear your cache. also don't forget to accept the answer since it fixed the original question.

Comment: It doesn't redirect to https:user.example.com/test from example.com/test and http:example.com/test.
I am sorry but I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer

Comment: These two are the same `example.com/test` and `http://example.com/test`, it's just if you're using chrome it hides the http:// so that part is irrelevant. However it does work. I updated the answer with a small change. Try it in another browser and/or clear your cache. You can test it http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/